# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'DynamicLinks'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, firebase-dynamic-links

Im getting this error while building iOS app.

Error showing on the line which I Bolded here

This is my code

```
@available(iOS 8.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    **guard let dynamicLinks = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks() else {**
        return false
    }
    let handled = dynamicLinks.handleUniversalLink(userActivity.webpageURL!) { (dynamiclink, error) in
        self.openURL(url: userActivity.webpageURL!)
    }

    if !handled {
        if let url = userActivity.webpageURL?.absoluteString {
            self.openURL(url: URL(string: url)!)
        }
    }
    return handled
}
```

Comment: It seems that that function doesn't return an optional, so you can't use a conditional assignment.

Comment: The **bold** tag has no effect within a code section. `dynamicLinks()` is obviously a non-optional so the guard statement is pointless. just write `let handled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink...`

Comment: @vadian i believe he was trying to show where his error was. :)

Comment: You do not need conditional assignment there. Replace the `guard let` with a simple assignment `let dynamicLinks = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks()`

Comment: @RakeshaShastri hi I replace the code with "let" but the error is still showing

Comment: @vadian I tried this let handled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink...  
but error is still there

Comment: I meant to delete also the entire `guard` expression.

Comment: @vadian after removing that expression I'm getting this error "Use of unresolved identifier 'dynamicLinks'"

Comment: If `DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks()` throws the *conditional binding* error the compiler does know the identifier. Are you sure you added the parentheses after `dynamicLinks` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks()` doesn't yield an optional result. Change your code to this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {

    let dl = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks()

    let handled = dl.handleUniversalLink(userActivity.webpageURL!) { (dynamiclink, error) in
        self.openURL(url: userActivity.webpageURL!)
    }

    if !handled {
        if let url = userActivity.webpageURL?.absoluteString {
            self.openURL(url: URL(string: url)!)
        }
    }
    return handled
}
```